# How can I determine why my toilets are not flushing right?

Tags: toilet

I just had all the stuff inside both toilet tanks replaced.  Now they aren't flushing right.  I checked inside the tanks and the water doesn't go all the way out.  It fills before it does so therefore you have to flush it twice or hold the handle down till it does.  What can I do to fix this problem?  Hopeing to hear from you.  Ruthann

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge most newer toilets manufactured after the water saving regulations were put in place do not completely empty the tank when they flush. The extra water is there to provide extra height to the water which increases the water pressure as it flows into the bowl.

If your toilet's flushing performance is fine then leave it as is. If not replace the flapper with an adjustable flapper. This can either be a flapper with a dial or a flapper with a float on the chain (you can even get the floats separately to add to your existing flapper chain). These help control how long the flapper stays open after you flush.

Comment: I'm still not sure how having to flush twice equates to a water savings ... If they'd have just allowed us to maintain our large tanks, we'd still just be flushing once. I do, however, like the partial flush mechanisms. I've installed several in the house and they seem to work well. Good answer though.

Comment: @Paulster2 Newer toilets are designed for low flow. New internals with old toilets not so great. The last one I installed is the best low flow toilet I've ever used. Never had to flush it twice so far. Check out my Optum Vormax review at http://tombuildsstuff.blogspot.com/2014/10/american-standard-optum-vormax-review.html That's my home improvement blog. Which partial flush mechanism did you get? Was looking for one but so many mixed reviews.